# Effective Way to Write RxJava Emissions to Text File?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

What is the most effective way to write an `Observable<T>` of items into a text file, where a line is written for each emission? I am using a `try-with-resources` setup below with a `CountDownLatch`, but it definitely feels like an anti-pattern due to the blocking. There is also a strong possibility of interruptions and early unsubscriptions throwing errors.

```
 private void saveToCSV(String url) {

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        File outputFile = new File(url);

        try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))) {

            writer.write(ReportItem.getHeaders() + "\r\n");

            reportItems.forDate(dt)
                    .map(ReportItem::toCSVLine).map(s -> s.concat("\r\n"))
                    .subscribe(Checked.a1(writer::write), Throwable::printStackTrace, latch::countDown);

            latch.await(); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: You can try implementing it with `Observable.using(this::getBufferedWriter, bufferedWriter -> Observable.just(bufferedWriter.write()), this::close);`

Comment: Can you show me with the OP example, and I'll mark as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a second thought, `Observable.using()` is perhaps not the best candidate here. I would try simply something like this (with `finallyDo()` instead):

```java
private void saveToCSV(String url) {
    BufferedWriter writer = getBufferedWriter(url);
    writer.write(ReportItem.getHeaders() + "\r\n");
    reportItems.forDate(dt)
               .map(ReportItem::toCSVLine).map(s -> s.concat("\r\n"))
               .finallyDo(() -> close(writer))
               .subscribe(Checked.a1(writer::write), Throwable::printStackTrace);
}

private void close(BufferedWriter writer) {
    try {
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private BufferedWriter getBufferedWriter(String url) {
    try {
        File outputFile = new File(url);
        return new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Let me play around with this.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasN. no problem, glad it helped